# Including fields that aren't on the model in to_representation in Django serializers

Tags: python, django

So I have a Django serializer and I am trying to get a certain output, but failing at it. Here's the serializer:

```
class MedTestsGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    test_type = MedTestsTypeNameSerializer(source='medteststypetest_id')

    class Meta:
        model = MedTests
        fields = ('medtests_id',
                  'test_type',)

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return '%s: %s' % (value.medtests_id, value.test_type)
```

Now theoretically, this should give me the output `{"uuid-goes-here-right-now": "test type name"}`, but it doesn't (and that's not even the final version of what I want).

It throws an error that says `'MedTests' object has no attribute 'test_type'`

Now my ultimate goal is to be in this form:

```
{"uuid-goes-here-right-now":{"test_type":"test name"}}
```

But I can't figure it out. How can I control the output to put a dict as a value to a uuid key, with the inner dict having a label as a key, and the inner dict having the value as the field. So basically this:

```
{VALUE OF MEDTESTS_ID: {"test_type": VALUE OF TEST_TYPE}}
```

As an FYI, MedTestsTypeNameSerializer just returns a string.

Comment: Is this the actual code that was generating the error? Based on the error it looks like you are calling `super`.

Comment: can you share your models please??

Comment: @dursk - you're right. Posted the wrong error from when I was trying to use a version with super(). Have fixed.